# Store Information about Purchase-State on Android securely

Tags: android, security, passwords

In my app the user will be able purchase the PRO Version from Google Play but also to redeem a code to activate the PRO Version.
Now my question is how can I store this information so that the user can not just go and change a boolean somewhere.

I'd like to have an equivalent of the Keychain on iOS. I did a bit of research and found f.e. this blog post about the Keychain on Android: http://nelenkov.blogspot.co.at/2012/05/storing-application-secrets-in-androids.html
The AccountManager thing seems not to do what I want?!?

The thing is though... I don't want to bother the user with anything like PIN protecting his phone what so ever. There should be no user interaction. I just want to make sure that the user can not edit information that I store on the phone. And then It should also sync to other devices like the Keychain on iOS.

What would you use to archive that? I'd need SharedPreferences that can NOT be edited by the user. I even don't care if he can SEE the setting, but NOT edit it... And it should automatically sync across the users devices...

Thanks and cheers

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use SharedPreferences? You can even write your information encrypted like explained here:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/549119/Encryption-Wrapper-for-Android-SharedPreferences

Another way would be to just write an file inside your apps scope.

Of course non of this solutions is 100% safe as the user can delete the app settings. For the sync matter I would use the standard android backup API:

http://developer.android.com/training/cloudsync/backupapi.html

Wether you store your information in an encrypted file or sharedPrefs, you could backup them and retrieve them via this API.

Comment: The problem with SharedPreferences is that values in there can easily be edited by the user on a rooted phone, isn't it? Even writing the data in there encrypted won't change a thing. One user just copies the content of an other user and he's done...

Comment: Yes this is true, although not many users would be able to do this. Can't you come up with a copy safe entry that is bound to an user id or even device id? Thus a copied entry isn't valid on another device?
What about an SQLite DB?